# How to build a Constructor for a Vector of pointers to classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, constructor

I need to build a constructor for a Vector of pointers to classes...

My class is :

```
class Song {

    string song_name;

    string auther_name;

    int popularity;

    SongStructure song_format;

    int song_length;

    int lengths[size];

    bool first_condition_true();

    bool second_condition_true(int index);

    }

};
```

My vector is :

```
vector<Song*> play_list;
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? The std::vector<Song*> already has a constructor, you don't have to create that one.

Comment: Yes, and your problem is?

Answer (score 2):

With the new standard C++11 / 0x initializer list has been introduced:

I assume you wanted to create a SongBook class containing a vector of Song-Pointers and then additional Infos.
They can be used like this:

Class file:

```
class SongBook {
    vector<Song*> songlist;
    string name;

    // Constructor
    SongBook(std::initializer_list<Song*> songs) : songlist(songs) {}
}
```

and then call like this from your main for example

```
SongBook book({new Song(...), new Song(...), new Song(...)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your vector have a working constructor that you can use. (It create place for the pointers). What you are asking for is probably a way to make the pointers point to some valid `Song`. You will need to do that in some loop (STL "loop" probably). But you probably dont need that, becouse your Song is legaly copyable!?. You can use `vector<Song>`